# Sandcastle 2.7 - What installer is it using?

Tags: .net, installation, sandcastle

Having just downloaded and installed the latest version of Sandcastle I was impressed with the installation process. Does anyone know what was used to make the installer?

http://sandcastlestyles.codeplex.com/releases/view/86091

In particular, points of elegance in the installation include:

1. A progress tree on the left indicating the total number of steps to completion.
2. Clearly defined instructions for each step of the installation process.
3. Where certain steps are not compulsory the user is given the option of skipping the step.

I would like to use something similar for an upcoming C# project?
Any information on what they've used is appreciated...

Comment: The great thing about open source is that the source is available :-)  Their installer is part of the project, download the project's source code archive and look for the installer in Extras\Sandcastleinstaller.  But you're right, it's great.

Comment: Great suggestion.... I didn't even think of that.
For those interested the source code can be found at:
http://sandcastlestyles.codeplex.com/downloads/get/368071

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After taking a quick look over the installer I would say the EXE was custom built, without using any dedicated setup authoring tools. If you look in "InstallResources" folder found next to it you will find the actual MSI package, which has the standard UI, which I suspect the EXE calls using a dynamic command line, so it installs the resources based on the user's selection.

Also, the rest of the packages I must assume that are set to be automatically downloaded from their publishers servers, as this is standard practice.

However, the source code should give you more details about its implementation.